# imgur - снова 503

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, imgur

Свежие примеры ссылок (взял из [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729355/178988)):

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv7rJ.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOEBl.png

Ну и скриншот, который сейчас не работает:

[image: скриншот, который сейчас не работает]

PS: Не работает как https, так и http.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мы связались с imgur'ом - похоже, они исправили ошибку.

---

We got in touch with imgur - seems they have fixed the issue on their end.